# Concate Two Member Of List In New Select And Bind To DataGridview Column

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-6

I wants to join for table from sql with lambda code
i use list for any table and join them
in one table i have "name" and "family" that i need to concat them to veiw fullname in datagrid view but i cat do that
Please guide me and if there is a better solution, I would appreciate it
my code :

```
 var listPartner = db.BusinessPartnerRepository.GetAllPartners();
        var listEvidence = db.Evidence.Get();
        var listDetail = db.EvidenceDetail.Get();
        var listCountry = db.Country.Get();
        var result = (from evidence in listEvidence
                      join detail in listDetail
                      on evidence.Id equals detail.EvidenceId
                      join countryname in listCountry
                      on evidence.CountryId equals countryname.Id
                      join partner in listPartner
                      on evidence.PartnerId equals partner.Id
                      select new
                      {
                          evidence.TruckNo,
                          evidence.SerialNo,
                          evidence.Date,
                          partner.Name.Concat(" "+partner.Familly).ToString() ,
                          detail.Id,
                          detail.EvidenceId,
                          detail.MerchandiseName,
                          detail.weight,
                          detail.Unit,
                          detail.Discription,
                          countryname.CountryName
                      }).ToList();
        dgEvidenceList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgEvidenceList.DataSource = result;
```

the code of "Get" method:

```
  public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
        if (where != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(where);
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

the code of "GetAllPartners" method:

```
public List<BusinessPartners> GetAllPartners()
    {
        return db.BusinessPartners.ToList();
    }
```

Relation:
the "Evidence" entity have feilds that be foreignKey:

PartnerId ---> Pk in BusinessPartner

CountryId ---> Pk in Country

evidenceId --> Pk in Evidence

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be quite new to C# and Entity Framework. I would advise looking up a few guides.

I am not quite sure if I understand what is your intent. I will try to answer your question as best as I can. Since you are using Entity Framework, you should be interacting with your tables using LINQ and the extension methods entity framework provides. It will make your life easier.

I assume the definition of your class `Evidence` looks similar to this:

```
public class Evidence
{
    //...
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public Partner Partner { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

You can then use `Include` to join your tables together:

```
List<Evidence> evidences = db.Evidence
    .Include(e => e.Detail)
    .Include(e => e.Country)
    .Include(e => e.Partner).ToList();
```

You should be able to then use this list of Evidences as data for your DataGrid. However, if you want/need to flatten it to a table of strings, you can do this:

```
List<List<string>> table = evidences.Select(e => new List<string>()
{
    e.TruckNo,
    e.SerialNo,
    //...
}).ToList();
```

If you need to join two strings together with a space between, you have many options:

```
// standard string concatenation
string1 + " " + string2
// string interpolation
$"{string1} {string2}"
```

I hope I answered your question. Again, I really recommend looking up some C# and Entity Framework guides.